セキュリティやProxyによってリクエストが失敗する環境を再現する方法を探しています
ブラウザ上のアプリケーションからリクエストを送ることを想定しています。例えば、 fetch("https//example.com")とリクエストしたとき、次のようなエラーが観測されることがあります。（CORSなどの基本的な設定は行われている前提です）
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

観測方法は、DevToolを利用して確認したもので、Sentryなどのログ集計ツール上ではFailed to Fetchのみ送信されています。
いくつかは運用しているサービスのGatewayやServer側の設定によって解決できるものと考えています。ただし、現在悩んでいるのはこのエラーをどうやって再現するか、というところです。
ユーザーの利用しているセキュリティソフトやProxyをすべて買い、検証するという手もありますが予算の許す限りとなります。また、設定方法をすべて教えてもらう、というのも現実的ではありません。
このようなユーザーの利用している環境（セキュリティソフト・Proxy）を再現する手段、サービス、ソフトウェアはありませんでしょうか。有償無償は問いません。

ご所望の状況が適えられるとすれば、カスタマーサポートで使用するような遠隔サポートツールで、当該コンピュータへリモートアクセスして情報を収集するくらいではないでしょうか。全てのソフトウェアやネットワーク環境を再現するよりも、かかる費用は抑えられると思います。

VirusTotalやブラックリストデータベースと照合することで、ドメイン名やIPアドレスがユーザーが導入しているセキュリティソフトやフィルタリングツールによりブロックされている可能性を確かめるという方法もありますが、ご所望のようにすべてのソフトウェアを網羅するのは難しそうです。

なるほど、確かにカスタマーサポートのツールとしての側面は考えていませんでした。これは一考の余地がありそうです。
網羅的〜に、という方も回答はあるていど想定はしていたものの、やはり当事者環境でない限り推論の域を出ないので、こちらも直接コンタクトが取れるようにする支援が必要そうですね。コメントありがとうございます。

まだ当方でも回答が見出せていないので、回答を引き続き受け付けた状態にします。
